# Users receive “Package file was not signed correctly” on older Android devices upon Google Play Store update

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, jarsigner

Upon attempting to install a Android update, the user receives an error "Package file was not signed correctly."  Specifically this error is only being encountered by users with devices on older Android OS versions.

Updates were made from current production app version to updated production app.  No development devices, side loading, etc. were involved.

The new version of the app is compiled with API > 21, thus requiring Java 1.7.

The apk is built, signed, and aligned using Gradle via Groovy config files as part of a CI build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Gradle build script step involving `jarsigner` specifies the algorithm to be used.

Part of a Gradle task to sign your .apk file with `jarsigner` might look like this:

```
ant.signjar(jar: packageRelease.outputs.files.singleFile,
                alias: 'keyStoreAlias',
                keystore: file('../keystore/keystore.jks').canonicalPath,
                storepass: 'cCureP@55',
                sigalg: 'SHA1withRSA',
                digestalg: 'SHA1',
                signedjar: outputFile.canonicalPath)
```

The key are these two arguments:

- **sigalg: 'SHA1withRSA'**
- **digestalg: 'SHA1'**

It appears that the new default algorithm used by the `jarsigner` in Java 1.7 is not understood by devices based on Java 1.6.

[Android developer documentation specifies these arguments](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually), but doesn't identify these arguments as critical to avoiding this type of installation/update error.

Here's a snippet from the part of the documentation showing you the steps to sign your app manually:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```